# After upgrade to SonarQube 5.3 Cobertura test coverage is missing

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, cobertura

I recently upgraded to SonarQube 5.3 and now test coverage using Cobertura is no longer published/analyzed.

It looks like JaCoCo is default code coverage no matter what we install or configure. Log shows that SonarQube is looking and not finding JaCoCo reports.

Is there still support for Cobertura with 5.3?

I tried to configure cobertura but `sonar.java.coveragePlugin` does not seem to do much anymore. You can specify what you like using this property but the JaCoCo will be used.

```
[INFO] JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : E:\myproject\jacoco.exec
[INFO] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: E:\myproject\jacoco-it.exec
```

Answer (score 2):

Since SonarQube 4.2 the test report isn’t generated by SonarQube anymore (see [SonarQube blog post](http://www.sonarqube.org/unit-test-execution-in-sonarqube/) for more information). So you have to do it by your own before you run the sonar analyze. For Maven builds, I wrote a [sample](https://github.com/sparsick/sonarqube-test-report-with-maven) how to integrate JaCoCo test reporting generation into a Maven build.

For Cobertura, you have to install the [Cobertura Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Cobertura+Plugin) for SonarQube. On that site it is explained how to generate the reports.

Comment: But can we still use Cobertura?

Comment: Yes, but you have to install Cobertura Plugin in SonarQube. On the [plugin site] (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Cobertura+Plugin) you can find some information about the report generation.